# TicTacToe using regex in java

Tags: java, regex, tic-tac-toe

using regex to do create a tictactoe
function which receives a string of nine "X", "O", and/or "-" characters representing the state of a tic tac toe board, for example the string:`"X-OXXXO-O"`
this represents:

```
X-O
XXX
O-O
```

some more examples:

```
"XOOOXXXXO" - False - no one got three in a row here.

"OXO-XOX-O" - True - player O won by getting three in a row vertically in the third column.
```

here is my attempt at writing the code:

```
public static boolean regexTicTacToeWinChecker(String b) {
        return b.matches("(((^(...)*000(...)*$)|(.*0..0..0.*)|(0(...0{2}))|(.(.0){3}..))) | (((^(...)*XXX(...)*$)|(.*X..X..X.*)|(X(...X){2})|(.(.X){3}..)))");
    }
```

using regex is much more useful then writing a lot of if's which cover all the cases. so answers with rejex please, help would be appreciated. thanks
here are some tests that you can use to check:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

public class ExampleTestCases {
    @Test
    public void SomeBoardsWithWinnersTests () {
      String[] winners = new String[]{"XXX-O-O-O", "X--OOOX-X", "O--OO-XXX", "O-XOX-O-X", "OXOOXOXX-", "X-O-OOXXO", "XO--X-OOX", "X-OXOOOXX"};
      for (String winner : winners) {
            System.out.println("Testing with board " + winner);
            assertEquals(true, RegexTicTacToeWinChecker.regexTicTacToeWinChecker(winner));
      }
    }

    @Test
    public void SomeBoardsWithoutWinnersTests () {
      String[] notWinners = new String[]{"XO-------", "XX-XOO---", "-XX-OO-O-", "OXO--XXO-", "OOXXXO---", "OXXX-XOO-", "OOXXX----", "XXOOXXOO-", "OXOXOX---"};
      for (String notWinner : notWinners) {
            System.out.println("Testing with board " + notWinner);
            assertEquals(false, RegexTicTacToeWinChecker.regexTicTacToeWinChecker(notWinner));
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*using regex is much more useful then writing a lot of if's which cover all the cases*" yet you wrote the regex [and here you are asking a question about it](https://xkcd.com/1171/). Likely wouldn't have happened if you used `if`s. And you *still* have effectively `if` statements by using alternation (`|`) in the regex. Just because it's not the keyword `if` doesn't mean the code doesn't branch.

Comment: Two answers down.  Anybody feeling lucky here? `:-)`

Comment: You could help those who answer by providing a comprehensive set of test cases.

Comment: just added it now. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break it down into the individual cases:

Horizontal match:

```
(?:...){0,2}([OX])\1\1
```

Vertical match:

```
.{0,2}([OX])..\2..\2
```

Diagonal match (two directions):

```
 ([OX])...\3...\3
 ..([OX]).\4.\4
```

Now, you just have to `or` them all together and make sure that the regex matches at the beginning of the board string:

```
^(?:(?:...){0,2}([OX])\1\1|.{0,2}([OX])..\2..\2|([OX])...\3...\3|..([OX]).\4.\4)
```

---

Edit: Here's a small Java program to test the regex:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class TicTacToe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:...){0,2}([OX])\\1\\1|.{0,2}([OX])..\\2..\\2|([OX])...\\3...\\3|..([OX]).\\4.\\4)");

    String board = "XXX-O-O-O";
 
    Matcher m = r.matcher(board);
    System.out.println(m.lookingAt() ? "match" : "no match");
    }
}
```

Comment: No, just test all edge cases in a demo and paste the link in your answer.  I like using Regex101.

Comment: @Thomas the belief that the code you wrote works increases the less tests you have. This is called Faith Driven Development. :P

Comment: @Thomas doesn't work  when testing; Testing with board `XXX-O-O-O`
Illegal repetition near index 6
```(?:...){,2}([OX]) | .{,2}([OX]).... | ([OX]).{4}.{4}..([OX]).. |``` and Testing with board `XO-------`
Illegal repetition near index 6
```(?:...){,2}([OX]) | .{,2}([OX]).... | ([OX]).{4}.{4}..([OX]).. |```
      ^

Comment: Hey, didn't I just tell you *not* to test it?

Comment: All kidding aside - there's slight differences between different regex dialects. The above works for python3 at least.

Comment: Yep, it was a dialect thing: Java regex's don't like `{,m}` -- you have to always give an explicit first argument (min number of matches): `{n,m}`. I edited the answer accordingly and also provided a small test program.

Comment: @Thomas [A bit more tests with your solution here](https://ideone.com/yZzoiK)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to maintain your regex in few months time, I'd rather go for something more readable than overly smart to be honest, e.g.;

```
Vertical match:   X..X..X..|.X..X..X.|..X..X..X
Horizontal match: XXX......|...XXX...|......XXX
Diagonal match:   X...X...X|..X.X.X..
```

Together:

```
^(?:X..X..X..|.X..X..X.|..X..X..X|XXX......|...XXX...|......XXX|X...X...X|..X.X.X..)$
```

This makes the winning patterns almost visible just by looking at the regex.

Do the same with `O`, and you should be good to go :)

Comment: Readable regexs? What weird concept is that?

Comment: @Thomas [RFC822](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) can't answer that either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer keeping your regex as simple as possible! This means that you need to stop cramping everything up to one string.

Imagine the following:

```
XOX
OOX
XXO
```

Why not creating several strings out of that like:

1. horizontal line: `XOX`
2. horizontal line: `OOX`
3. horizontal line: `XXO`

and

1. vertical line: `XOX`
2. vertical line: `OOX`
3. vertical line: `XXO`

and

1. top-lef diagonal line: `XOO`
2. bottom-left diagonal line: `XOX`

And run each of those values against:

```
"^X{3}$" = player 1 won
"^O{3}$" = player 2 won
```

In code:

```
Pattern player1Pattern = Pattern.compile("^X{3}$");
Pattern player2Pattern = Pattern.compile("^O{3}$");
for(String s: tictactoe) {
    if(player1Pattern.matcher(s).matches()){
         //Player 1 wins
    }else if(player2Pattern.matcher(s).matches()){
         //Player 2 wins
    }else{
         //nobody wins
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

See [regex-demo](https://regexr.com/5h363)

I just take the input as a pattern input:

```
X-O
XXX
O-O
```

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([XO])(?:(?:\\1\\1)|(?:(?:[\\sXO-]{2}\\1){2})|(?:[\\sXO-]{3}\\1){2}|(?:[\\sXO-]{4}\\1){2})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("X-O\n" +
                "XXX\n" +
                "O-O");
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if(matchFound) {
            System.out.println("Match found and "+ matcher.group(1) + " win!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Match not found!");
        }
```

Output:

```
Match found and X win!
```